# matlab: how to create matrix by shift vector

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have row and column in matlab:

a = [1 0 3 ... a_k]; - row 1xk

b = [1;0;3; ... b_k]; - column kx1

I want to create new matrix's (A and B) mxn, that can be populate by shift row and column:

```
A = [1 0 3 0 0 0 0 ... 0;
     0 1 0 3 0 0 0 ... 0;
     0 0 1 0 3 0 0 ... 0;
     ...
     0 0 0 0 0 0 ... 1 0 3 ]

B=  [1 0 0 0 0 0 0 ... 0;
     0 1 0 0 0 0 0 ... 0;
     3 0 1 0 0 0 0 ... 0;
     0 3 0 1 0 0 0 ... 0;
     0 0 3 0 1 0 0 ... 0;
     ... 
     0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ... 3]
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
>> a = [1 0 3];
>> m = 5; %// number of rows
>> A = convmtx(a,m)
A =
     1     0     3     0     0     0     0
     0     1     0     3     0     0     0
     0     0     1     0     3     0     0
     0     0     0     1     0     3     0
     0     0     0     0     1     0     3

>> b = [1;0;3];
>> m = 4; %// number of columns
>> B = convmtx(b,m)
B =
     1     0     0     0
     0     1     0     0
     3     0     1     0
     0     3     0     1
     0     0     3     0
     0     0     0     3
```

Comment: Nifty. I didn't know about the `convmtx` function.

Comment: @MrAzzaman Thanks! Actually I remembered about that function from a Q&A here the other day :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in a slightly tricky way by using a combination of indexing and `bsxfun`. First we want to create an index matrix that represents the shift that we're trying to. It should look like this (at least for `A`):

```
1  2  3  4 ...  k
k  1  2  3 ...  k-1
etc
```

To create this, we can use `bsxfun` as follows:

```
index = mod(bsxfun(@plus,1:k,-(1:(k-2))'),k)+1;
```

We can then create the matrix `A` by using this as an index matrix for `a`:

```
A = a(index);
```

The matrix `B` is the same, just transposed:

```
B = b(index)';
```

Comment: I have custom row/column. Not incremental.

Comment: `a = [1 0 3];

k=10;

index = mod(bsxfun(@plus,1:k,-(1:k)'),k)+1;

A = a(index);`

??? Index exceeds matrix dimensions.